# Is Athene's Theory of Everything a respectable theory?

Tags: theory-of-everything

[Athene's Theory of Everything](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dbh5l0b2-0o) is a *very* popular youtube video proposing a "theory of everything":

[image: screenshot of video on youtube]

**How respectable is this video?** Is it complete hogwash, or is there an element of truth to it? Can someone with the necessary experience in physics please debunk or validate the contents of this video once and for all.

Comment: As is written in [this meta post](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/453), *We are not a substitute for peer-review, and cannot evaluate new theories*.

Comment: It is unreasonable to expect that people watch a one-hour video on YouTube to evaluate its claims. To improve this post, you could place a link to a concise summary of the claims made - although the post might still be outside of the scope of this site.

Comment: This is a real shame. Similar questions have been closed for the same reason at other places the internet. I am no doubt one of thousands (millions...) of people looking for an expert's perspective on this. This video desperately needs reviewing publicly from someone who knows what they're talking about, whether it's here or not.

Comment: Dear George, while I sympathize with your calls for scientists to interact with such claims, you should also try to understand that those 2.5 million viewers who devour this stuff are clearly not experts and experts (and even semi-educated people) turn off this video after a minute or so because it's clearly a crackpot's video addressed to the undemanding viewers. I don't want to spend hours by debunking the video in detail because my benefits would be negative - negative votes from some folks angry that I have pointed out that their hero is a crank. So I prefer to write is as a comment. ;-)

Comment: The video is an incoherent mixture of comments about the society, thinking, mirroring the society, hunger, etc., and hundreds of other random distractions. Except for claims to the contrary, it has nothing to do with physics. At some point, it starts to offer buzzwords like arrow of time, mass etc., except that it never gives any coherent answers to any questions. So it's not physics and it's not a theory. It is totally stupid.

Comment: Okay thanks for your responses. I was worried it would be closed. I thought maybe 2.5 million views would make it *debatably* mainstream.

Comment: @GeorgePowell: You *clearly* don't know what mainstreamj is. Youtube is full of idiots (such as this gamer "athene"), like it or not.

Comment: you can post questions like this on Quora.com

Comment: I found this http://bin.smwcentral.net/u/16068/athene%2527s%2Btheory%2Bof%2Beverything.pdf write up . I agree with Lubos' comments.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's obvious that this "theory" is a completely informal rant. And that, together with the fact that he draws on concepts which are far removed from the usual physicists lingua, indicates that the video probably contains no new ideas. He essentially drops keywords from basic quantum mechanics/relativity.

But he looks cute and pronounces "Einstein" correctly.

Comment: It's unnecessary to be rude.  You can take the same time to ask him to be specific.

Comment: @Catzmuze: Him? The youtuber?